# What are the details of the story of Indra giving the Crest-jewel(chudamani) to king Janka?

Tags: puranas, ramayana, indra, janaka

The son of the wind-god,Hanuman, apprised Sri Rama(avatar of god Vishnu) about the discovery of Sita(avatar of goddess Lakshmi),on  returning  to Kishkindha (from Lanka).Then Hanuman delivered to  Sri Rama the jewel for the head(Chudamani), earlier handed-over by Sita as a token:-

> Then, untying the bright divine jewel for her head tied in her garment, Seetha gave it to Hanuma, saying that it might be handed over to Rama….5-38-69

Hanuman also conveyed Sita’s message to Sri Rama. Sita’s words:-

> This beautiful jewel for the head has been well-guarded by me. You also ought to recall a mark indeed painted by you (by slip) on the curve of my cheek with powder of an orange-red rock, when my former mark on my forehead got effaced." 5-65-22

Sita, further said:-

> This beautiful jewel, which has its origin in sea-water, has been sent to you. Seeing this in my grief, I am feeling always happy as though I am seeing you."-shloka 5-65-23.

Sri Rama, on seeing that excellent jewel,spoke to Sugreeva as follows:-

> This excellent jewel was presented by my father-in-law to Seetha when she had become a bride and was tied to her head in such a way that it looked additionally beautifying.—shloka 5-66-4

Sri Rama, further described the jewel, as under:-

> The jewel, which was found in the waters and recommended by the pious, had been presented to him(king Janaka) earlier by the intelligent Indra the lord of celestials, who was highly pleased in Yajna, a sacrificial rite (intended to propitiate him).--shloka 5-66-5

From the foregoing, it can be inferred that the jewel for the head or the Crest-jewel(Chudamani) worn by  Sita was earlier obtained during the Samudra Manthan(churning of the Ocean of Milk) and kept with demigod Indra. And Indra, at a later date, gave it to king Janaka on completion of a yajna(sacrificial rite) by king Janaka  to propitiate him.

Which  specific yajna(sacrifice ritual) was conducted by king Janaka to propitiate demigod Indra?

What are the details of the story of Indra giving the Crest-jewel(Chudamani) to king Janaka?

Reference- [Valmiki Ramayana,Book Five-Sundara Kanda](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/vr_index.htm)

Answer (score 2):

In Ayodhya Kanda, while narrating her Swayamvara (selection of bridegroom), Sita says to Anasuya, wife of Atri as follows:

> महा यज्ने तदा तस्य वरुणेन महात्मना |
>   दत्तम् धनुर् वरम् प्रीत्या तूणी च अक्षय्य सायकौ || २-११८-३९
>
> "In ancient days, Janaka received with affection from Varuna the rain-god, an excellent bow with two quivers that should never lack arrows."

The jewel, which Sita used wear, was found in the waters of Varuna.  Varuna might have accompanied Indra , I presume, to the Yagna of King Janaka.  Indra might have given that jewel to Janaka and Varuna might have given bows to him.

Comment: " Varuna might have accompanied Indra , I presume, to the Yagna of King Janaka. Indra might have given that jewel to Janaka and Varuna might have given bows to him." Looks like this is your assumption. But you should quote sources for all important points in your answer. Meanwhile i will add Post Notice and flags mods to remove it after quoting sources.

Comment: Yes.   It is my presumption.   In Valmiki Ramayana,  no other reference was available as to when Janaka was gifted with the jewel by Indra.@Destroyer

Comment: Yes. You can search for other sources like Puranas.

Comment: Sorry.  I don't believe major part of Puranas as authentic versions.  So I cannot quote Puranas, as the OP is asking something from Valmiki Ramayana.  If my answer is found incorrect, it can be deleted.@TheDestroyer

Comment: @TheDestroyer: Further, if any other sources like Puranas contain reference to the question of OP, many writers in this site could have offered the same by now, as the OP posted his question in 2018 itself.